# Syntax error on $$ double dollars in Postgres function creation

Tags: bash, postgresql, function, heredoc

I am attempting to create a simple function during the startup of a postgres instance. I am doing this by mapping some `.sh` files to the `/docker-entrypoint-initdb.d` dir.

I continuously hit a problem with this simple function.

```
#!/bin/bash
set -e

psql -v ON_ERROR_STOP=1 --username "$POSTGRES_USER" --dbname "$POSTGRES_DB" <<-EOSQL
    CREATE OR REPLACE FUNCTION hi() RETURNS TEXT AS $$
    BEGIN
        RETURN 'hi'
    END;
    $$;
EOSQL
```

```
2020-01-29 05:12:30.817 UTC [62] ERROR:  syntax error at or near "1" at character 49
2020-01-29 05:12:30.817 UTC [62] STATEMENT:  CREATE OR REPLACE FUNCTION hi() RETURNS TEXT AS 1
        BEGIN
            RETURN 'hi'
        END;
ERROR:  syntax error at or near "1"
LINE 1: CREATE OR REPLACE FUNCTION hi() RETURNS TEXT AS 1
```

If I change it to something with actual content:

```
#!/bin/bash
set -e

psql -v ON_ERROR_STOP=1 --username "$POSTGRES_USER" --dbname "$POSTGRES_DB" <<-EOSQL
    CREATE OR REPLACE FUNCTION hi() RETURNS TEXT AS $func$
    BEGIN
        RETURN 'hi'
    END;
    $func$;
EOSQL
```

I get another error at the same place:

```
2020-01-29 05:17:36.161 UTC [62] ERROR:  syntax error at or near "$" at character 49
2020-01-29 05:17:36.161 UTC [62] STATEMENT:  CREATE OR REPLACE FUNCTION hi() RETURNS TEXT AS $
        BEGIN
            RETURN 'hi'
        END;
ERROR:  syntax error at or near "$"
LINE 1: CREATE OR REPLACE FUNCTION hi() RETURNS TEXT AS $
```

**Running with the latest postgres version: 12.1**

What precisely is the problem with this function definition and why am I getting this error?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

The part of your script from `<<-EOSQL` to `EOSQL` is called a "here document", and that functionality is documented at [the *Bash Reference Manual*, §3.6.6 "Here Documents"](https://www.gnu.org/software/bash/manual/bash.html#Here-Documents). Per that section:

> If any part of *word* [in your case `EOSQL`] is quoted, […] the lines in the here-document are not expanded. If *word* is unquoted, all lines of the here-document are subjected to parameter expansion, command substitution, and arithmetic expansion, […]

In other words — because you haven't quoted any part of `EOSQL`, Bash is performing parameter expansion (and other similar substitutions) on the contents of the here-document, which includes replacing `$$` with the process-ID, and `$func` with the empty string, before PostgreSQL sees them.

If you just change `<<-EOSQL` to `<<-'EOSQL'`, it won't do that.

Comment: Thanks! That did the trick. Could you quote that paragraph explaining it?

Comment: @MirroredFate: Sure -- done.

Comment: Just a side note - do not add quotes to the closing mark, `EOSQL` in this case.

Answer (score 2):

`$func` and `$$` are variables in `bash`. The first one is the process ID of the shell instance, which explains the number in your error output; the second is just a normal user-defined variable, presumably empty, so `$test$` becomes just `$` (as `$test` gets replaced by an empty string).

You can either escape the dollar sign that `bash` finds significant, using `\$\$` and `\$test\$`, or you can use `<<-'EOSQL'` to use single-quote (no variable substitution) semantics on the heredoc.

None of this has to do with PostgreSQL, it's `bash` doing what it thinks you want.